# Что такое перелом интонации при постановке запятой и тире как единого знака?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Мне не очень ясно, что такое "перелом интонации" (термин у Розенталя). Когда мы меняем запятую на тире и паузой делим предложение на две части, то разве это нельзя считать переломом интонации?

И еще : почему Розенталь в следующих предложениях "ставит" тире, а не запятую и тире (там есть слово ЭТО и однородные придаточные).Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять. Голова ли думает, сердце ли чувствует или руки перевёртывают стаканы — всё покрывается равными плесками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, перелом интонации бывает обычно в середине предложения: до середины восходящая интонация, после неё - нисходящая. Но для постановки запятой и тире как единого знака  это не единственное условие. Нужно, чтобы это было сложное синтаксическое целое, иногда период. Вот в периоде, особенно представляющем собой сложноподчинённое предложение, большая пауза делит предложение на две части. Первая часть нанизывает придаточные, целый ряд,которые читаются с восходящей интонацией и маленькими паузами между ними, а потом - большая пауза и интонация падает.В середине - фразовое ударение, после него спад. Вот тогда это  условие для постановки запятой и тире как единого знака.

*Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять*.Здесь изъяснительное придаточное подчёркивается интонационно, стоит впереди главного - ставим тире

*Голова ли думает, сердце ли чувствует или руки перевёртывают стаканы — всё покрывается равными плесками.* -  перелом интонации, разделяя конструкцию на две части, устанавливает причинно-следственные отношения между ними, как в бессоюзной конструкции, поэтому тире.

Но если б это был Толстой, он бы поставил и запятую, чтобы привязать последнее предложение к остальным.

Comment: Да. спасибо, теперь понятно. Запятая и тире обозначают прелом интонации в конструкциях, состоящих из двух сложных частей. Пауза при этом подчеркивается, имеет большую длительность, чем для простого тире.